# function for post from category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following  function in functions.php page

```
function viewpost($num)
{
   echo $num;
   query_posts('order=dsc&cat=$num & showposts=2');
   while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
   ?> <span> <?php  the_title(); ?> 
   <?Php 
   echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
   the_excerpt();
   ?> 
  <?Php 
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();  
}
```

When I call viewpost function for  values of `viewpost(1)`(to view post from  category one ) it shows correct values, but when I put the same function again `viewpost(2)` (to view post from  category 2) it shows the previous function values i.e. from category. What can I do to get the post from different categories by changing the passing value

Comment: Why are you using this much of php tags?

Comment: this is not an answer . am new in php and also in stack overflow.

Comment: That wasn't supposed to be an answer. This is the comments field. When people want clarifications about your question they ask you things here. If someone has an answer, it will get posted later in the fields below.

Comment: am not interested to chat here. Now i realizing that so many peoples are wandering here to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without trying your code, I think the most likely problem is you're using single quotes.  Variable names won't get expanded to their values.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php).

Try

```
query_posts("order=dsc&cat=$num&showposts=2");
```

instead of

```
query_posts('order=dsc&cat=$num & showposts=2');
```

[This might](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) be worth a read too.  Using `query_posts` is normally not recommended.

Comment: you saved me from big problem beacuse am new in wordpress thats why am scaring .Thank  you Hobo. Thank  you very much..